# What is the correct type to use for an ObjectId field across mongoose and GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Following [this tutorial](https://www.compose.com/articles/using-graphql-with-mongodb/), I have a mongoose model:  (I'm using the term "Account" instead of "Todo", but it's the same thing)

```
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', new mongoose.Schema({
  id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String
}));
```

and a GraphQLObjectType:

```
const AccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'account',
  fields: function () {
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLID
      },
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and a GraphQL mutation to create one of these:

```
const mutationCreateType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    add: {
      type: AccountType,
      description: 'Create new account',
      args: {
        name: {
          name: 'Account Name',
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        }
      },
      resolve: (root, args) => {
        const newAccount = new Account({
          name: args.name
        });

        newAccount.id = newAccount._id;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          newAccount.save(err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(newAccount);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

After running the query:

```
mutation {
  add(name: "Potato")
  {
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

in GraphiQL, I get the response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "ID cannot represent value: { _bsontype: \"ObjectID\", id: <Buffer 5b 94 eb ca e7 4f 2d 06 43 a6 92 20> }",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 33,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "add",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "add": {
      "id": null,
      "name": "Potato"
    }
  }
}
```

The creation of the object was successful, and I can see it in MongoDB Compass:

[image: From MongoDB Compass showing created object]

but there seems to be a problem reading the value.

How compatible are `GraphQLID` and `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` ?  If they are not compatible, am I misunderstanding the tutorial, particularly it's use of:

```
newAccount.id = newAccount._id;
```

?  I can't tell if the error is being thrown by GraphQL, or MongoDB, or Mongoose, or something else entirely.

**EDIT**

Any information on the error

> ID cannot represent value: { _bsontype: \"ObjectID\", id:  }

would be *very* helpful.  I feel it's telling me it couldn't serialize a BSON object .. but then it displays it serialized.  Even knowing what tech (mongo? mongoose? graphql?) was generating the error would help.  I'm not having any luck with Google.

**EDIT 2**

This was a caused by [a change](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/1382) to the graphql package introduced recently, and there is [a PR](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/1520) awaiting merge which resolves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find an issue and ran this code with one of my existing code bases. Except I wrapped the mutation in the `GraphQLObjectType`.

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addAccount: {
            type: AccountType,
            description: 'Create new account',
            args: {
                name: {
                    name: 'Account Name',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                }
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => {
                const newAccount = new Account({
                    name: args.name
                });

                newAccount.id = newAccount._id;

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    newAccount.save(err => {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        else resolve(newAccount);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

To get the working example: [Clone](https://github.com/shivamkrpandey/accounts-stoverflow) the repo. In this repo, the app uses `v0.13.2` and you are using `v14.0.2` installed via `npm i graphql`. Downgrade `graphql` to `v0.13.2`.

Comment: Thanks; I'm doing the same further on (not sure why it's split).  I would really appreciate your working example thank you

Comment: These kinda bugs are a PITA ... I wonder if it's a subtle configuration thing, or something related to the version of node/mongo/mongoose/graphql/something else I'm using :(

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I have edited my answer with repo link. Thanks

Comment: Yours works perfect.  I notice you used graphql `v0.13.2` - I was using `v14.0.2`.  Downgrading mine to the same version, the problem went away.  Interesting, because `npm i graphql` installs `14.0.2`. (Note: I spent several hours banging my head before I figured this out - thank you for your example!)

Comment: If you add this information to your answer I will tick it ;)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Added suggested info and thanks to you too for figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

I used `ID` and it works fine! cause of your problem is not id's type! it's becuase you provide it with wrong value: `ObjectID('actuall id')`

In order to fix this issue, call `toJson` function for each fetched data, or simply add a virtual `id` like this:

```
YourSchema.virtual('id').get(function() {
    return this.toJSON()._id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what I just found is that `_id` is of type `ObjectID` but seems to implicitly cast to `String`. So if you define your mongoose model id type to be `String` instead of `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` then it should work. Using your current code (from the compose.com tutorial) that copies _id to id, the result will be that, in Mongo (after saving), the _id will be of type `ObjectID` and your model id will be of type string.

In other words, instead of this

```
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', new mongoose.Schema({
  id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String
}));
```

Do this

```
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String
}));
```

Comment: Wonder if this practice affect the usage of  ```populate``` in mongoose?

Comment: Meteor js will use string ids at the default but be careful that you are drifting away from the default behaviour of Mongo
Correctly supporting ObjectId is often preferable, if only to respect Mongo default behaviour